# php file_get_contents returns false

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

i´m trying to include some code from the own server via an api / brigde / whatever...

```
    class ZKBrigde {

    private $_url;

    public function __construct() {
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

        $script = explode('/', $script);
        array_pop($script);
        $this->_url = "http://" . $host . implode('/', $script) . '/zk/';
    }
```

Here i´m looking for the main url of the target framework.

In an request im using this (example, $items is an integer):

```
return file_get_contents($this->_url . "brigde/acp/page/changelog/$items");
```

First, this has worked. In some cases if i have an error in my code, it don´t work, returns false. OK, i´ve fixed the errors.

Now, changed some code of the backend, it doesnt work.
If i type the URL in my browser, i get the required result, no errors.
With this now i always get the result "FALSE".

How to check what is wrong?
Any hints to make it better?

(It should be an API / Brigde to my CMS)

lg., Kai

Comment: You sure you're not mis-typing something? `brigde` in your last `return` sample looks wrong.. `bridge`, perhaps? did you `echo` out your generated url and cut/paste it into your browser? Don't depend on you having re-typed it correctly.

Comment: no, nothing mistyped. its overall 'brigde'. - I´ve printed out the url and tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $this->_url = trim("http://" . $host . implode('/', $script) . '/zk/');
```

And try if the URL are clear and in a good format!

```
class ZKBrigde {

private $_url;

public function __construct() {
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    $script = explode('/', $script);
    array_pop($script);
    $this->_url = trim("http://" . $host . implode('/', $script) . '/zk/');
    $open = open("test.txt", "w");fwrite($open, $this->_url);fclose($open);
}
```

Take a look in test.txt when you've tested the script.

Comment: Trim does not work. I´ve printed out the url many times - and its always working.

Comment: If there in a URL double Slash (//) file_get_contents dont support this, you might use: $this->_url = "http://" . str_replace("//", "/", $host . implode('/', $script) . '/zk/');

Comment: Before it has worked - with double slash. In all examples i´ve seen there double slashs (how to tell php to look "online"? - tell him the protocol). I´ve tryed the full url.

Comment: Try directly <?=file_get_contents(YOUR URL);?> to see if problem came from the function or your remote website. If came from the function, you can use CURL to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP's documentation if your path has special characters and you are trying to open an URI, then you need to use urlencode() function. Does your path have special characters? I'd use urlencode to be in the safe side.

https://www.php.net/file_get_contents